# How to get facebook user's hometown and location with JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I'm using this code:

```
function testAPI() {
console.log("Welcome! Fetching your information...");
      FB.api('/me', function(response) { 

var name=response.first_name;
var last-name=response.last_name;
var birthday=response.birthday;
var activities=response.activities;          
var email=response.email;           
var gender=response.gender;          

    });
```

I tried to get user's hometown and location this way:

```
var hometown=response.hometown.name;
var location=response.location.name;
```

It works only for my personal Facebook account and for all others it doesn't work. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What accesstoken are you using?

Comment: I'm not using accesstoken . Can i get hometown and location without accesstoken ?

Comment: Without an access token none of this would work :)
You're lacking the user_location and user_hometown permissions.

Comment: Ok. I put this kind of permission in facebook login:  <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email, user_hometown, user_location" show-faces="true"width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>

How can i get now hometown and location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to request the appropriate fields via Field Expansion:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,gender,activities,location,hometown,email,birthday', function(response) {
    ...
}
```

To get all the info you want to show, you'll additionally need to following permissions:

- `user_activities`
- `user_birthday`